# List all azure resources with tagnames and tagvalues using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to fetch OperatingHours tag details for all the Azure VirtualMachines and Azure SqlDatabases.
Following are the possibility for appID in a resource and the values I need to print in output correspondingly:

1. If OperatingHours tag itself is not present in any resource then display "Tag not present"
2. if OperatingHours tag is present but contains null or empty string then display "NULL/EMPTY"
3. if OperatingHours tag is present with any other value then display that value.

Do I need to take care of option (2) separately or is it like printing any normal value of the OperatingHours.

After long efforts I have created following script:

```
$ErrorOccured = $false
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | 
             Where-Object {($_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines") -or ($_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases")} |
 foreach {
   new-object psobject -Property @{
        ResourceName = $_.ResourceName;
        ResourceType = $_.ResourceType;
        OperatingHours= try { 
                         $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; 
                         ($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours;     }
                       catch { 
                         $ErrorOccured = $true ;                }
                       if ($ErrorOccured) 
                         {  "Tag not present"  } 
                       else { 
                         ($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours;
                         $ErrorOccured = $false };}
         }
$resources | Format-Table
```

When running this script, I am receiving following error:

```
At line:13 char:58
+                                                         }
+                                                          ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
At line:20 char:2
+  }
+  ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncompleteHashLiteral
```

If I replace the OperatingHours statement with following code then the script is running with success. But in doing so, I am not able to satisfy the option (1) mentioned above.

```
Operating Hours =   if (!($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours) 
                       {"Tag not present"} 
                    else {($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours} ;
```

Please advise me on how to correct this and get the required output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of hit and trial and rigorous testing, I found what I was looking for:

```
OperatingHours = if ( ($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours -ieq $null ) 
                     {"TAG NOT PRESENT"} 
                 elseif ( ($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours -ieq '') 
                     {"NULL/EMPTY"} 
                 else 
                     {($_ | select -expand Tags).OperatingHours } ;
```

I replaced the OperatingHours statement in original script to above.

The solution looks easy and after finding it I was like how could I miss that earlier, but that's what learning process is all about, right ?